# More Pyglet - Supress mouse motion events?

Tags: python, events, pyglet

In the same game as last time, I've ran into a new problem. When I move the mouse, FPS increases from around 60 to over 500. I know what you're thinking; it's not because of `on_draw()` getting fired each event (I think), since I already did override of `pyglet.app.EventLoop.idle`:

```
class EventLoop:
    def idle(self):
        pyglet.clock.tick(poll=True)
        return pyglet.clock.get_sleep_time(sleep_idle=True)

pyglet.app.EventLoop = EventLoop()
```

Also I call `flip()` on the window in my drawing function. All the useless mouse motion events take up a lot of CPU, which is annoying. What can I do about it?

**Edit**

I added `window.invalid = False` to my drawing function and `window.invalid = True` to my update function, this seems to reduce CPU usage with other mouse actions.

**Edit 2**

The drawing function is a typical `on_draw()` function.

**Edit 3**

After some more investigating, it seems that all those events don't take that much CPU as I thought they would. Still it would be good to know if this is the way Pyglet is supposed to act, or if it's something that should be avoided.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using pyglet in python, why does my frame rate speed up if I mouse-drag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523931/using-pyglet-in-python-why-does-my-frame-rate-speed-up-if-i-mouse-drag)

Comment: I do both `schedule_interval` and `set_fps_limit`, and the game runs 60-80 fps without events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you should be doing on mouse events is updating your apps' model of the input control state and using that in the next regular scheduled update and redisplay of the world model (which is presumably much more complex with physics and rendering and stuff).

ie just because mouse events come in at ~300fps doesn't mean you actually have to do all the stuff you want to do at 300fps.

It's been a while since I did any Pyglet, but the pattern I seemed to use was to subclass Pyglet's `window.Window` as `MyGameWindow`, then that registered event handlers like

```
   @self.event
    def on_mouse_motion(x,y,dx,dy):
        self.mouse_position=(x,y)
        self.mouse_buttons=0
        self.invalid = False
```

(also `on_mouse_drag`, `on_mouse_press`, `on_mouse_release`).  Hmmm... actually, I think that assignment to `self.invalid` might have been crucial for overriding Pyglet's default behaviour and defering any further updating/drawing until the next "clock tick".

Comment: This is another solution to what I'm doing now, it seems it doesn't matter if you set `self.invalid = False` in mouse motion event, or in `on_draw()`. You have to set it to `True` once you want the screen to be redrawn, for example in your update function. Also, the mouse events still trigger clock ticks so the FPS counter by `ClockDisplay` goes nuts.